# Match media to detect preferred color scheme isn't working for Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm trying to implement a Dark Mode according to the user's system settings. To do so I use the @media query `prefers-color-scheme: dark`. This works, but I do also need to make some checking in JavaScript.

```
detectColorScheme() {
   if (!window.matchMedia) {
     return false;
   } else if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark').matches) {
     this.isDarkMode = true;
   }
}
```

This code works fine for Chrome, but not for Safari. It still returns false (solely for Safari), even though system dark mode is activated.

Comment: Did you mean to have a closing parenthesis `)` after `prefers-color-scheme: dark`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing parenthesis ) in your code.
The updated code:

```js
detectColorScheme() {
   if (!window.matchMedia) {
     return false;
   } else if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
     this.isDarkMode = true;
   }
}
```

Another examples:

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches
window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion)').matches
window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches
```